# emscripten window.onload equivalent

Tags: javascript, html, c, emscripten

I have a single html file where I copy paste the emscripten generated code into it's `<script></script>` region
The browsers run the emscripten code before all the html file has been processed
So if the emscripten code uses an html element that is after the `<script></script>` region, it won't work
[here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#how-can-i-tell-when-the-page-is-fully-loaded-and-it-is-safe-to-call-compiled-functions) it says that the C main() function is called after the page is fully loaded but that is wrong
How can I make the C code run after the html file is fully loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [page](http://lyceum-allotments.github.io/2016/06/emscripten-and-sdl2-tutorial-part-7-get-naked-owl/) is a tutorial-style guide to using Emscripten to compile to JavaScript and including that JavaScript in your own page. It includes not running the C program until a button is clicked on the HTML document.

In short, normally, rather than copy and pasting Emscripten generated code, it is easier to load the Emscripten JavaScript in a separate request, for example, in your main document by running the JavaScript:

```
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = "my_emscripten_script.js";
      document.body.appendChild(script);
```

In Emscripten you don't need to have a `main` function at all, that tutorial I link to renames the `main` function `mainf`, if you export it by passing the command line flag

```
      -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_mainf"]'
```

to `emcc` at compile time (note the leading underscore!) and then you can call it from JavaScript when you want to start your C program. How you call an exported function from JavaScript is described [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#calling-compiled-c-functions-from-javascript-using-ccall-cwrap), but for the renamed `mainf` function will be a JavaScript call like this:

```
Module.ccall('mainf', null, null);
```

If you want to make sure that that isn't called until the Emscripten run-time is ready, the `Module` object that Emscripten uses can have a `onRuntimeInitialized` method added to it. This function is called when Emscripten is ready, so you can use this for doing your call to `ccall` to start the program.

Having said all this, I am surprised that your `main` function is being run before the document is ready. Please be aware that some of the emscripten functions in `html5.h` (such as the functions for requesting the canvas goes full-screen) are only functional upon user initiated events (for security reasons), so it could be that that is your problem rather than at what point during page load `main` is called.